# AWS SSM port forwarding : Not able to restrict port

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

How can I restrict the ports that is open for port forwarding in AWS SSM. I've cloned the publicly available SSM document `AWS-StartPortForwardingSession`.

Trying to edit the `allowedPattern` parameter from accepting the regular expression for all ports in between `1024` to `65535` to accept only 4 port numbers (3142,4200,121,1300).

I've tried using JSON array to specify the needed port numbers but it is gining the error
`InvalidDocumentContent: JSON not well-formed. at Line: 15, Column: 25`

The original SSM document content

```
{
  "schemaVersion":"1.0",
  "description":"Document to start port forwarding session over Session Manager",
  "sessionType":"Port",
  "parameters":{
    "portNumber":{
      "type":"String",
      "description":"(Optional) Port number of the server on the instance",
      "allowedPattern":"^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])$",
      "default": "80"
    },
    "localPortNumber":{
      "type":"String",
      "description":"(Optional) Port number on local machine to forward traffic to. An open port is chosen at run-time if not provided",
      "allowedPattern":"^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])$",
      "default": "0"
    }
  },
  "properties":{
    "portNumber":"{{ portNumber }}",
    "type":"LocalPortForwarding",
    "localPortNumber":"{{ localPortNumber }}"
  }
}
```

The code that I've cloned, edited and which is not working

```
{
  "schemaVersion":"1.0",
  "description":"Document to start port forwarding session over Session Manager",
  "sessionType":"Port",
  "parameters":{
    "portNumber":{
      "type":"String",
      "description":"(Optional) Port number of the server on the instance",
      "allowedPattern":"^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])$",
      "default": "80"
    },
    "localPortNumber":{
      "type":"String",
      "description":"(Optional) Port number on local machine to forward traffic to. An open port is chosen at run-time if not provided",
      "allowedPattern": ["9200","9042","13000","389"],
      "default": "0"
    }
  },
  "properties":{
    "portNumber":"{{ portNumber }}",
    "type":"LocalPortForwarding",
    "localPortNumber":"{{ localPortNumber }}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is because you are specifying a list instead of a pattern.  Try this regex:

```
"(3142|4200|121|1300)"
```

To be clear, the quotes are not part of the regex, the entire line above is a string value for your AllowedPattern

Comment: Feel free to accept this answer so I can eventually be StackOverflow Karma God

Comment: Do you maybe know if there is any other way to limit SSM document parameters like IAM policy?